# My underscore template won't render my collection in my Backbone App

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm new to backbone and have been working on my first app. I've been trying to display a collection through an underscore template, however my content isn't showing up. The template exists in require, and an html file is being pulled in, it's defined as venderDetail.

My assumption is that my object isn't being passed into the template markup but I'm not sure the way to test inside the html to see if it exists.

Here is my code that handles my collection/models/views:

```
// Define our object that will contain our modals, collections, and views
    var SimpleVendor = {
        Models : {},
        Collections : {},
        Views : {}
    }

    // Define our Modal
    SimpleVendor.Models.Vendor = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            firstName : '',
            lastName : '',
            address : '',
            city : '',
            state : '',
            zip : '',
            venue : '',
            website : '',
            eventDate : '',
            summary : ''
        },
        urlRoot : '/vendor'
    });

    SimpleVendor.Collections.Vendors = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : SimpleVendor.Models.Vendor,
        url : '/vendor'
    });

    SimpleVendor.Views.VendorsList = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName : '<li>',

        template : _.template(vendorDetail),

        className : 'vendorDir',

        initialize: function() {
            console.log(this.template);
        },

        render : function () {

            var vendors = this.collection.toJSON();

            this.$el.html( _.template(this.template, vendors) );

            return this;
        }   
    });
```

Here is my template:

```
 <% _.each(vendors, function(vendor) { %>
    <li><% vendor %></li>
    <li class="first-name">
        <h1><%= vendor.get('firstName') %></h1>
    </li>
    <li class="last-name">
        <h2><%= vendor.get('lastName') %></h2>
    </li>
    <li class="address">
        <span><%= vendor.get('address') %></span>
    </li>
    <li class="city">
        <span><%= vendor.get('city') %></span>
    </li>
    <li class="state">
        <span><%= vendor.get('state') %></span>
    </li>
    <li class="zip">
        <span><%= vendor.get('zip') %></span>
    </li>
    <li class="venue">
        <strong style="font-weight:bold">
            <%= vendor.get('venue') %>
        </strong>
    </li>
    <li class="event-date">
        <span>
            <%= vendor.get('eventDate') %>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="summary">
        <p><%= vendor.get('summary') %></p>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

Here is where I instantiate new instances:

```
// Some Vendors
var someVendors = [ 
{
    firstName : 'Mister', 
    lastName : 'Jones', 
    address : '48 Allston Street', 
    city : 'Boston', 
    state : 'MA', 
    zip : '02125', 
    venue : 'Royale', 
    eventDate : '07/21/2015', 
    summary : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sunt eligendi consectetur ab natus iusto obcaecati temporibus nisi explicabo adipisci quia amet ullam maiores culpa cumque ipsum consequuntur nulla neque.'
},    
{
    firstName : 'Rick',
    lastName : 'James', 
    address : '48 Orchard Street', 
    city : 'New York', 
    state : 'NY', 
    zip : '02125', 
    venue : 'House of Blues', 
    eventDate : '06/11/2015', 
    summary : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus sunt eligendi consectetur ab natus iusto obcaecati temporibus nisi explicabo adipisci quia amet ullam maiores culpa cumque ipsum consequuntur nulla neque.'
}

];


$(function(){   

    // Define Model
    var vendor = new SimpleVendor.Models.Vendor({});

    // Data
    var vendors = new SimpleVendor.Collections.Vendors(); // End Data

    vendors.reset(someVendors);

    var vendorList = new SimpleVendor.Views.VendorsList({
        el : 'section ul',
        collection : vendors, 
        model : vendor
    });

    $('section ul').append(vendorList.render().el);


})
```

I'm slowly learning but have been stuck on this issue.

Comment: As far as I remember - the element provided to Backbone.View cannot be jquery object. Use 
    el : $('.section ul').get(0),

With the above change the last "append" call will be unnecessary

Comment: @wookieb The `el` attribute you pass to a view can be a DOM node, a jQuery object or a string that will be considered as a selector

Answer (score 4):

1. In `_.template(this.template, vendors)`, you're recompiling an already compiled template. Undescore expects a string as its first argument but receives a function and chokes on it. <sup>1</sup> Since you have your template as a property of the view, use

   ```
   var html = this.template(...);
   this.$el.html(html);
   ```
2. You're passing an array to your template (`this.collection.toJSON()`) but it expects an object having a `vendors` key. Use

   ```
   var html = this.template({
       vendors: vendors
   });
   ```
3. By using `this.collection.toJSON()` you convert your collection of Backbone models to an array of plain objects. That means that your template can't use the models' methods but has to use the dot notations : `vendor.firstName` instead of `vendor.get('firstName')`, `vendor.lastName` instead of `vendor.get('lastName')` and so on
4. Finally, you already pass your DOM node to your view, you don't need to render/append/etc. Use

   ```
   var vendorList = new SimpleVendor.Views.VendorsList({
       el : $('.section ul'),
       collection : vendors, 
       model : vendor
   });

   vendorList.render();
   ```

See http://jsfiddle.net/vrqfeLa5/ for a demo

<sup>1</sup> Note that immediately passing the data to [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) is deprecated. You must first compile the template and then use it : `_.template(source as string)(data)`